# Spout Receiver / OpenGL in C# - Incorrect Syntax

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm trying to create an application that receives a sequence of images by Spout but I can not figure out the exact logic to it ...
I've never worked with OpenGL so do not know much about the correct syntax ...

All information is from the help here and looks very well explained ... but I could not properly understand how to put this logic to work ...

https://github.com/matjacques/LightjamsSpout

Below is my code and all I get is just a static image ...
I'm getting the result of a Bitmap and putting in a PictureBox ...

How do I put these images in an OpenGL object type?

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            string senderName = "";
            var receiver = new LightjamsSpoutLib.LightjamsSpoutReceiver();
            int nbSenders = receiver.NbSenders();
            for (int t = 0; t < nbSenders; ++t)
            {
                string name; int w, h;
                receiver.GetSenderInfo(t, out name, out w, out h);
                lblConnection.Text = name;
                senderName = name;

                // can instanciate the object in any thread
                LightjamsSpoutLib.GLContext m_glContext = new LightjamsSpoutLib.GLContext();
                m_glContext.Create();

                LightjamsSpoutLib.LightjamsSpoutReceiver m_receiver = new LightjamsSpoutLib.LightjamsSpoutReceiver();

                // the senderName as retrieved when enumerating senders or "" to use the active sender
                int m_width = 500;
                int m_height = 500;
                m_receiver.Connect(senderName, out m_width, out m_height);
                Bitmap m_bitmap = new Bitmap(m_width, m_height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

                const int bytesPerPixel = 3;
                int stride = 4 * ((m_width * bytesPerPixel + 3) / 4);
                byte[] m_buffer = new byte[stride * m_height];

                var data = m_bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, m_width, m_height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                m_receiver.ReceiveImageIntPtr((long)data.Scan0, LightjamsSpoutLib.EPixelFormat.BGR);
                m_bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

                // Put in PictureBox (Only Static)
                PictureBox Screen = new PictureBox();
                Screen.Height = m_height;
                Screen.Width = m_width;
                Screen.Image = m_bitmap;
                this.Controls.Add(Screen);
            }

        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I test your code and just have no more of 6 or 7fps, i just run a timer for emulate pickup 30fps, but performance is really poor. Have some idea why?